# Do one time (once) execution in forever loop or void loop?

Tags: c++, c, oop, arduino

I want make one time or once execution syntax inside forever loop (void loop) for any program languages.

What i found the solution is with make new variable boolean "executed" and set to true after executed.

It's okay, but what if i want do once execution to other syntax? Should i make new variable boolean again? It will not effecient. Imagine theres many syntax but i must make new bool executiin for each syntax.

The solution is function i think

For example

```
void loop()
{
lcd.print("OK");
}
```

THIS IS WILL PRINT FOREVER
I wish theres function like this

```
void loop()
{
once(lcd.print("OK"));
}
```

so "once" is a function with parameter string which its for command/syntax.

once("command")

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27832896/2041317 .  Does that fix your problem?

Comment: I have seen it. But it destroys the void loop, i want void loop keep running with some syntax i choose do once in void loop. And i can do activate again next time with still once whenever i want in void loop.

Comment: Is there a subtle difference between doing the loop once same as destroying the loop?

Comment: Destroying what i mean is like break;

Comment: Have you looked at @philomech's solutions further down?

Comment: Yeah thats what i said on thread, his solution using booelan for one session "if". Imagine if theres many session. So i need make new boolean variable again as much as possible?

Comment: That sounds like @philomech's solution #3.

Comment: Could you explain your specific case? This might be an XY problem and solvable in a completely different way.

Comment: Im making simple operating system on Arduino. And it little complicated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Several ways to approach this

Following is a very common way of how such an operation is usual made.
As you already suggested, with an **global boolean**:

```
bool once = true; // global variable
void loop() {
  if (once) { // being called only once
    lcd.print("OK");
    once = false;
  }
}
```

Do something only once **after a specific time**:

```
void loop() {
  // millis() is the time in milliseconds after the startup 
  //if you want to print something once after a specific amount of time
  //this also includes a little "wait time" of 100 milliseconds as the statement might be asked with a delay
  if (mills() >= 1000 && mills() <= 1100) {// time in milliseconds
    lcd.print("OK");
  }
}
```

And thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096366/how-to-stop-a-loop-arduino/27832896#27832896) thread, with **exiting the loop** (might be not what you are searching for):

```
void loop() {
  lcd.print("OK");
  exit(0);  //The 0 is required to prevent compile error.
}
```

But I suppose you are trying to make some kind of an interface, where a specific answer is printed regarding to the user input (probably many possibilities)?!
In that case it kind of depends on what inputs you are getting:

In case of **Integers**:

```
void loop() {
  switch (input) { //input must be an integer
    case 0:
      lcd.print("OK"); //prints "ok" if input is 0
    case 1:
      lcd.print("Hello"); //prints "Hello" if input is 1
  }
}
```

In case of **Stings/chars**, you need to go with an "if loop" trough every possible input(or with an array of Strings/chars):

```
void loop() {
  lcd.print("Turn off?"); //asks if it should do something
  if (input == "yes") { //String input
    lcd.print("OK, shut down!");
    //do something
  }
  else if (input == 'n' || input == 'N') { //char input
    lcd.print("OK, no shut down!");
    //do something
  }
}
```

A function you are looking for, where a specific answer only prints ONCE regarding to an input can be **just archived by if/else** loops. If a String should be just printed once at startup, print it in the "setup()" constructor. Otherwise just with **global booleans** something like that is possible.

Note that those are only my suggestions based on my experience, but it does not necessarily mean that other solutions are not available.
Hope that helps still :)

Comment: Yeah u true.. im making interface on arduino

Comment: In case of string/char, how can "input" has dual type of data? (String and char)

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira yeah you are right! There are no dual types, as far as I am aware of. Still for completeness I thought putting a char and String data type there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can do it:

```cpp
void loop()
{
    { // execute once. Can put this in a separate function also
        static bool executed = (lcd.print("OK"), true);
    }
}
```

You're guaranteed that this variable is initialized once.

If you want the `once` syntax in your question, you can achieve something similar with a macro:

```cpp
#define ONCE(...) \
{\
 static bool executed = ([&]{__VA_ARGS__;}(), true); \
}


void loop()
{
    ONCE(lcd.print("OK"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++, there is [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) which is even multi_thread, then you can do it generically:

```
template <typename F>
void simple_do_once(F f)
{
    static std::once_flag flag;
    std::call_once(flag, f);
}
```

As lambda have unique type, you have one flag by lambda:

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a65be292ec95252)