# Switching between finite and infinite for loop based on input parameters

Tags: c++, arduino

I want to blink an LED for a finite number of times or infinite times as per the user input. I am not sure how to switch between these two tasks.

```cpp
  for (i = 0; i < REPEAT; i++) {
    //Blink LED code here
  }
```

As per the above snippet `REPEAT` defines the number of times the LED is to be blinked.

My question is how to make it work continuously. Is there any way of removing the parameters inside the 'for' loop: `for(;;)`

The above snippet was just a shortened version of what I am actually working on.

The real scenario is:

I am working on an RF signal generator using an AD9957 which is controlled using an STM32. This device has the ability to generate 1 - 500 MHZ RF.

I have created the control to write the internal registers of this device to perform an RF frequency sweep, for which I need to have control over the iterations of the sweep. It can either be a defined value of an infinite one.

Here is the actual snippet of my work:

```cpp
int REPEAT = Serial.read(); // Iterations may be Finite[1-100] or Infinite[0]
    
for (i = 0; i < REPEAT; i++) { 
  for (FQ = SFQ ; FQ <= EFQ ; FQ = (FQ + STEP)) {
    // code for writing AD9957 Registers 
    // also monitor user input for breaking out in case of infinate looping.
  }
}
```

I am using the `break` function to break out in infinite loop condition.

**Long story short:**

I want to switch between `for(;;)` and `for (i = 0; i < REPEAT; i++)` based on user input.

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Please only tag one programming language tag that is relevant to your question.

Comment: I suggest you to go through unfamiliar constructs line by line and read relevant parts in the book. This way you will become familiar with the language instead of coming to comunity ato ask simple language concepts. this example will run the loop infinitelly regardless of REPEAT value : ```bool infinite = true;for (i = 0; i < REPEAT || infinite; i++)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code might help.

```
for (i = 0; i < REPEAT; i++)
    { //Blink LED code here;
      if(input==0){ //Set input variable as 0 if it is an infinite loop. You can change this condition if needed
          REPEAT++;
    }
}
```

The value of REPEAT gets incremented when you increment the value of i so the loop will be an infinite loop.

**Note**: I have noticed that you tagged Arduino so if you are using Arduino, any blink code written in loop() will be repeated infinitely (even if you define finite for loop inside loop() ). To exit from loop(), you can use exit(0);

Please check the following answer for more details:
[1]: [how to stop a loop arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096366/how-to-stop-a-loop-arduino)

Comment: Hi Jerrymon, Thank you for your response, I think this will help me out, I'll try this and get back. :)

Answer (score 2):

Take input, make a switching condition on input and select the loop that you want.
Basically something like.

You can move the switching condition inside if it helps

```
int main()
{
int n;string x; cin>>n>>x;
{
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    i = (x=="FINITE")?i:i-1;
    cout<<"OK"<<endl;
    ; //your task
}}}
```

```
    //original answer
    int n ; string x; cin>>n>>x;
    if(x=="FINITE")
    {
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            ; //your task
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while(1)
        {
            ; //your task 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi vaibav,Sorry, This method won't be helpful in my case as this will increase the code size and is not a good practice to rewrite the same set of codes.

Comment: You can move the switching condition inside too. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but here's two alternatives:

Set a boolean flag `forever` and test it in the conditional clause:

```
for ( i = 0; forever || i < REPEAT; i++ ) { ... }
```

The problem is `i` will keep incrementing and will eventually overflow.

Second, write your own loop:

```
i = 0;
while ( true ) {
    if ( !forever || i >= REPEAT ) {
        break;
    }
    blink();
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The structure of the `for`loop is:

```
for(initialization; condition; increment/decrement)
{
    // your statements
}
```

You can avoid any of these three according to your need.

1. For infinite loop use this one, here i put nothing in the increment/decrement and condition part of the `for` loop

```
for(int i = 0; ;){
    // your statements
}
```

or, can avoid all the fields in the for loop:

```
for(;;){
    // your statements
}
```

2. For finite loop use this one:

```
for(int i = 0; i < REPEAT; i++){
    // your statements
}
```

3. You can also use `while` loop, like below, this while loop will run infinitely as we gave `1` and it represents the condition is always true.

```
while(1)
{
    // your statments    
}
```

Now you can take the input from user, and check whether the user want finite number of times or infinite number of times, and then use these two ways according to the user input.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I have now elaborated my question, kindly review it once more time.